# postgresql log time

Tags: postgresql, time, logging

I'm using postgresql-8.3.0
The time in postgres log is different from now()
Here is an example from postgres log:

```
<2011-06-29 14:50:44 JST postgres xxxx 24962>LOG: duration: 4398046.715 ms statement: select id from mcontents where id='00005324' and (start_date <= '2011-06-29 13:37:26' and (end_date IS NULL OR end_date >= '2011-06-29 13:37:26'));
```

System time is 2011-06-29 13:37:26 and now() is OK but the log time is 2011-06-29 14:50:44.
Please help.

Comment: Wait, stop.  If you're running 8.3.0 you're missing over three years of updates.  No matter what else we cover here, running an old .0 pg release is only one step from running an older rc or beta build in terms of asking for trouble. You should really really upgrade.  If I remember correctly there are data eating bugs in 8.3.0.  OK, back to the other issues you're having.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your duration interval is that long (4398046.715 ms is ~ 73 minutes) and log time `%t` is calculated at end of that query:

```
13:37 + 73 mins = 14:50
```

**EDIT:**

You shouldn't use minor version 8.3.0 in any production environment, really. According to [PostgreSQL's FAQ](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ):

> It is strongly recommended that you
>   **always** upgrade to the
>   latest minor release.

Comment: But i get this log after the above one
<2011-06-29 13:43:56 JST postgres xxxx 26677>LOG: duration: 4398046.846 ms statement: select id from mcontents where id='00005092' and (start_date <= '2011-06-29 13:43:56' and (end_date IS NULL OR end_date >= '2011-06-29 13:43:56'));

Comment: @yoyo-yuan: That looks weird. Can you check that two queries under psql or pgadmin3 and find out real duration ? If possible use latest minor version of PostgreSQL 8.3, that is 8.3.15. You can check your version using `SELECT version()`.

Comment: The real duration is fast 0.xx ms.I can't understand why always 73 mins+ the real duration.

Comment: Ok，finally I got something about this.My server is running as a guest on the vmware host.So sometime the system's time just jump to the future. sorry,postgres.